# How do I diagnose a 2007 VW Passat 2.0T B6 FSI BPY engine failure?

Tags: vw, cranks-wont-run, passat

My 2007 VW Passat 2.0T B6 FSI BPY engine quit running at idle with no prior warning indicators, and no MILs or DTCs subsequently. The starter engages but doesn't turn over the engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm assuming by you stating the start engages but doesn't turn over, you actually mean the starter turns the engine over (makes it go around), but it doesn't want to run? (I've adjusted the tags according to this ... if it's wrong, please correct them.) Here's a stupid question for you: Are you sure you have fuel in the tank? Also, you'll want to ensure the fuel pump is running ... If you can hear it, you'll need to put a fuel pressure gauge on the fuel rail to see if you are getting fuel pressure. One place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks, Paulster2, I'm new here, and it took a while to make the complete post. Sorry that it is so much, but for someone like you it's a treasure trove to follow the story as it unwinds. I lived to tell. The YouTube video is my next project, to post it, to stand by as I do a final edit to include a reference to this text release.

Comment: Please remember that this is a question and answers site where we hope to help the next person recognize their problem in our contribution and to find a specific solution. As such, long form narrative does not help the next reader quickly parse and recognize “ah, this is what I need and now I know what to do!” The links to outside sites (e.g., blogs and YouTube) are *sometimes* useful for providing some additional context. We prefer that the Q&A format can stand on its own without help, though. Open ended discussions are always welcome in the chat, as well.

Comment: The answer was too long by 527 characters. Maybe I'll try later.